# Rails Controller Hash into Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

trying to change the structure of a JSON response using a serializer. I'm having problems though as I need to group the data alphabetically (`|one_record| one_record.name[0].to_s`) which is returning a hash at the moment. How could I go about converting this to an array that I can pass into the serializer?

```
    #WIP - order should return an array of contacts ordered alphabetically according to their name.
    def order
        # returns the first letter of the name
        @ordered_contacts = @user.all_contacts.group_by { |one_record| one_record.name[0].to_s }
        render json: @ordered_contacts, serializer: ContactshipsSerializer, :status => :ok
    end
```

Serializer:

```
class ContactshipsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  # method override
  def serializable_object(options={})
    @ordered_contacts.map do | *title*, ordered_contacts |
      [ *title* , serialized_ordered_contacts(ordered_contacts) ]
  end.to_h
  end

  private

    def serialized_contactships contactships
      ordered_contact.map{ |contactship| ContactshipsSerializer.new(ordered_contact, root: false) }
    end
end
```

Comment: If you're just looking for an array, `@user.all_contacts.group_by { |one_record| one_record.name[0].to_s }.to_a` will do the trick. But how does `ContactshipsSerializer` expect the data?

Comment: Hey, that makes sense. I wrote the question assuming that the error was coming from submitting a hash (new to serializer and JSON formatting) but I'm wrong it seems. Updated the question to include the serializer but mistake in title/group key?

Comment: If you only use the first letter of their name to organise them, this will not guarantee that they're sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Is there a way I can do that? This question is more about restructuring the JSON so I can pass it to React Native but it would good to know how to sort alphabetically